# Zend Framework 2 - Set Template Path for Module

Tags: php, templates, controller, zend-framework2, zend-view

I googled alot and couldn't come up with an answer...

I'm using the [tutorial-skeleton application](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/index.html#userguide). It automatically includes under 'view/album/album' the html files corresponding to my actions like add or index.

I'm using a submodule and the standard loading won't find my html-files. I followed [this guide](http://samminds.com/2012/08/changing-the-view-template-view-script/) for setting a custom template path. This works for the index because here I use a `ViewModel` instance.

But my add/delete/edit actions just return an array like [this one](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/user-guide/forms-and-actions.html#editing-an-album).

Is there a way to tell `Zend` that it should use a different directory to look for the views?

PS: I also tried this [injectTemplate approach](http://ctrl-f5.net/php/custom-default-templates-in-zf2/) but no luck. It just sets the Controller namespace/path which is ok in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an project specific issue...

I used `MasterData` as top namespace. When creating the directory tree in my module\MasterData\view I wrote `masterdata` instead of `master-data`. This caused the not finding of my views.

A dumb one... I know.

Comment: It's not dumb, it's simply things that are not really the most intuitive to starters. Every name inside the framework will be sanitized. Meaning: every key/name will be `lowercase` only. `CamelCase` turns into `dash-separated-lowercase`

Comment: Yes true, me too faced this issues and pulled my hairs for three days and finally found this digging the zendframework code